# Server always defaults to github.com with error message `Permission denied (publickey)`

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I'm trying to connect to a remote server via ssh but I always get redirected to github with an error message, even when I am not trying to connect to github:

```
ssh username@<anyServerName>
username@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Update: ran it with `-v` and the debug log looks something like this:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/zenghoulim/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/zenghoulim/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/zenghoulim/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/zenghoulim/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-26093308
debug1: no match: babeld-26093308
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'zenghou'
```

My `.ssh/config` file looks something like this:

```
# --- Sourcetree Generated ---
Host *
        HostName github.com
        User zenghou
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile /Users/zenghoulim/.ssh/id_rsa
        UseKeychain yes
        AddKeysToAgent yes
# ----------------------------
```

I've been trying to fix this for a week now but can't seem to find any solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem in your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
```

The `*` means "apply the following configuration to every SSH connection, regardless of which hostname you're using".

The next line, `HostName github.com` means "no matter which hostname you're writing on the command line, ssh should always connect to github.com.

If you don't want those lines of configurations to apply to all hosts, you should change the `Host *` to apply to only the hosts you actually want them for - perhaps `Host *.github.com` or whatever it is you actually want to use.